# Invalid initializer member declarator in unit test mock up

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a class

```
public class Restrictions
{
    [Key]
    public short RestrictionId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string BlockCode { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerRestrictions> CustomerRestrictions { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class CustomerRestrictions
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public CustomerContacts CustomerContacts { get; set; }
    public string RestrictionId { get; set; }
    public Restrictions Restrictions { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
public class CustomerContacts
{
    [Key]
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Btn { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerRestrictions> CustomerRestrictions { get; set; }
}
```

It seems to be many-to-many relationship.

Now I want to do a unit test for the controller. There is a similar [example.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api)
But it doesn't have many to many.

My controller is

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BtnRulesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBtnRulesRepository _btnRulesRepository;
    public BtnRulesController(IBtnRulesRepository btnRulesRepository)
    {
        _btnRulesRepository = btnRulesRepository;
    }
    // GET api/BtnRules
    [HttpGet]
    public IList<Restrictions> Get()
    {
        return _btnRulesRepository.GetRestrictions();
    }
```

The difficult thing is how to create sample data in unit test at this moment.

```
 public class SimpleBtnRulesControllerTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void GetAllBtnRules_Should_Return_All_BtnRules()
    {
        var repo = new Mock<IBtnRulesRepository>().Object;
        var controller = new BtnRulesController(repo);

        var testBtnRules = GetTestBtnRules();
        var result = controller.Get();
        Assert.Equal(testBtnRules.Count,result.Count);
    }

    public List<Restrictions> GetTestBtnRules()
    {
        var testBtnRules = new List<Restrictions>();

        var testCustomerRestrictionsList = new List<CustomerRestrictions>();
        var testCustomerRestrictions = new CustomerRestrictions();
        testCustomerRestrictions.CustomerId = 1;
        testCustomerRestrictions.RestrictionId = "1";
        testCustomerRestrictions.Restrictions=new Restrictions();
        testCustomerRestrictions.CustomerContacts=new CustomerContacts();
        testCustomerRestrictionsList.Add(new CustomerRestrictions());
        testBtnRules.Add(new Restrictions() {RestrictionId = 1, Description = "Demo1",BlockCode = "AdminBlock1",testCustomerRestrictionsList});
        testBtnRules.Add(new Restrictions() { RestrictionId = 2, Description = "Demo2", BlockCode = "AdminBlock2" ,testCustomerRestrictionsList});
        return testBtnRules;
    }
```

However I get the error CS0747  Invalid initializer member declarator.

Comment: You missed CustomerRestrictions  = testCustomerRestrictionsList. Instead you just pass testCustomerRestrictionsList into object initializer.

Comment: There is no where, where you are actually setting up what the `IBtnRulesRepository` is actually returning data. There isn't any `var mock = new Mock<IBtnRulesRepository>(); mock.Setup(x => x.GetRestrictions)... etc` And if you would like it to stay the way you have coded then you're doing an integration test....

Comment: @CallumLinington, good point. But in `Setup/Returns` I still need to send sample data. So I have to generate them by hard code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things incorrect with your code that I can see.

Firstly, when you are setting the `testCustomerRestrictionsList` you do not name the Property that it is being assigned to and this is the compiler error.
Your code should look like:

```
testBtnRules.Add(new Restrictions() {RestrictionId = 1, Description = "Demo1",BlockCode = "AdminBlock1", CustomerRestrictions = testCustomerRestrictionsList});
```

In this case I wouldn't worry too much about hardcoding the `Restrictions` into your unit test. But in the future you may want to look into something like [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) so that you don't need to worry so much about creating your objects.

Secondly, you are not setting up the call to the mock `IBtnRulesRepository` when the `GetRestrictions` method is called.

Your test should look like:

```
[Fact]
public void GetAllBtnRules_Should_Return_All_BtnRules()
{
    var repo = new Mock<IBtnRulesRepository>();

    var testBtnRules = GetTestBtnRules();

    repo.Setup(mock => mock.GetRestrictions())
        .Returns(testBtnRules)
        .Verifiable();

    var controller = new BtnRulesController(repo.Object);
    var result = controller.Get();
    Assert.Equal(testBtnRules.Count,result.Count);
    repo.Verify();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add it. But why in my code I have to  add `testBtnRules.ToArray`? Otherwise it is wrong.

Comment: @Love Where are you calling `ToArray()`? When you setup the `Returns`? I wouldn't think you'd have to since `List<T>` inherits from `IList<T>`.